# Asp.Net Assembly not being run

Tags: c#, iis

My current issue is that an assembly that I changed works on my localhost while debugging but I can't seem to get the new code to be recognized on a stage server that I copy the code to.

I hate to say it, but right now I can truthfully say "it runs on my machine". The good news is the same code works the same way in development on another persons machine as well.

I've opened the WebSite.dll with reflector and verified the disassembly to the source code and my new stuff is there.

I've also restarted the site and the App Pool and there's no old code hanging around that I can blame.

Is there some cache that I have to invalidate somewhere?

VS2010, C# 4.0, IIS7, Windows Server 2008.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: How exactly do you know your code is not running? How does this manifest?

Comment: Is the website configured for 4.0?

Comment: the code is not running as I can verify that it runs on two development machines and I can see the instruction in question in the assembly on the stage server. There's no size difference between the two assemblies. It's not perfect, but it'll do in the way of verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Three approches you can use depneding on what level of access is available to you.
**Use SysInternals [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).**

When you click on a process the DLLs are displayed in the lower pane. It will include where its loaded as a tooltip and you can select it as a column to display.

**Getting the Dll out of memory**

First get Memory Dump of ASPNET Worker process. [See this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/27827/how-can-i-grab-a-memory-dump-of-my-w3wp-exe-process) on how.
The accepted answer by Matt Everson is to use the SysInternals VMMap which...

> has command line options for
> scripting, and may give you the
> information you need.
>
> vmmap.exe -p w3wp.exe C:\memory.txt

Once you've done that you can use WinDbg to verify the Modules (Dlls) in memory. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150717191759/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2007/07/02/windbg-script-extracting-base-address-and-image-name-from-a-method-call.aspx) from Roberto Farah shows you how to do this and then extract it from memory to disk and then use reflector as you did before.

**Assembly Binding Log Viewer**

You can use use [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29) which will tell you exactly what is loaded and where it came from. This is a much better approach but requires you to make a registry change to turn on the logging which some people shy away from on Non-Dev boxes.

Comment: now that you mention sysinternals, I wonder if process explorer would have done the trick?? Just an idea in case I reference this later. This worked to find out the offending assembly. Thanks!

Comment: @Josh. You're totally right about that. I always forget about that. I'll add it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar issues before and it was a permissions issue running on your staging environment, if you are using reflection that might need to access some DLL in the GAC that could cause an issue, make sure your application pool has access to external libraries also...